# SCOM 2012R2 DFS Replication Managementpack

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs, dfs-r, system-center, scom

We have a functional implementation of SCOM 2012R2 running on Windows Server 2012R2. Recently I have begun trying to get the DFS Replication monitoring working; specifically backlog monitoring. However, it seems that only certain monitors are finding success. The fileservers in question are all Windows Server 2012R2 as well.

Our fileservers have begun throwing the following event ID 1102 for many of the rules/monitors from at least one of the DFSR management packs. The rule/monitor names in each of these events begin with one of either [Microsoft.Windows.Fileserver.DFSR.6.3.] or [Microsoft.Windows.Fileserver.DFSR.].  See Below:

> Rule/Monitor "Microsoft.Windows.FileServer.DFSR.BacklogDiscovery"
>   running for instance "DFS-14" with
>   id:"{6E648D77-AD11-AADC-E91B-B7F57FAE74C6}" cannot be initialized and
>   will not be loaded. Management group "Tervis"

I have ensured that the action account has administrative privileges, and each node is configured for Proxy. Strangely enough, I found that backlog monitoring normally seems to work at least once, after an agent reinstall; then starts erroring again. This is confirmed by the 'Microsoft Windows DFS Replication->Backlog Monitoring' monitor reflecting updated metrics.

Has anyone resolved this issue or can otherwise provide some direction to be sure configurations are correct?

Comment: Please check AddOn DFS Replication Management Pack on TechNet Gallery: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/AddOn-DFS-Replication-33d233a8 It addresses some of the shortcomings of the Microsoft MPs.